# Unittesting a table to determine that there are more than one record

Tags: c#, sql, testing, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create an `Assert.AreEqual` query that determines that the records in a given table do, in fact, contain `>= 1` (row/record)

I know the query will look something along the times of:

```
Assert.AreEqual(context.Count().Ticket_Number >= 1);
```

or

```
Assert.AreEqual(context[row].Ticket_Number.Count() >= 1);
```

This query returns 10,000 + rows:

```
SELECT [Ticket_Number] FROM dbo.SRS_Ticket_LifeCycle_Stage
```

It is the query I want to ensure has more than 1 record (For a test right after it that is expecting a return of nothing).

I do not know how to specifically target the rows with these statements any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so many rows you should use LINQ to SQL to filter the query to only return 1 result to maximize performance.

`Assert.IsTrue(sqlContext.TableName.FirstOrDefault(row => row.PrimaryKey != null) != null);`

We take the first row of the table that has a non-null PK and if there's a result then the test will pass.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this to get the count (then store the result in a variable to make your code cleaner):

```
SELECT COUNT([Ticket_Number]) FROM dbo.SRS_Ticket_LifeCycle_Stage
```

Now test the result using

```
Assert.IsTrue(resultFromSqlQuery >= 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to test a comparison, you might want to use `Assert.IsTrue` instead of `AreEqual` since you're not actually testing for equality. Let's assume that you can get your record count into a separate variable named recordCount:

```
Assert.IsTrue (recordCount >= 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the SQL way of determining if there is more than one record of something is to use the `EXISTS` keyword:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [Ticket_Number] FROM dbo.SRS_Ticket_LifeCycle_Stage)
   -- do something
```

Or, you could use `COUNT` to get the number of records:

```
SELECT COUNT([Ticket_Number]) FROM dbo.SRS_Ticket_LifeCycle_Stage
```